# JOLT get only one array out of multiple arrays with the same name

Tags: json, jolt

Hi I have a JSON with nested array that has different ids and values, I just want the first_id and it's value but I'm not sure how, I only know how to get all ids. See below

My JSON

```
{
  "rootid": "19718",
  "ids": [
    {
      "id": "first_id",
      "field2": "source",
      "value": "root_value"
    },
    {
      "id": "second_id",
      "field2": "source2",
      "value": "second_value"
    },
    {
      "id": "third_id",
      "field2": "source2",
      "value": "third_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

my Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "ids": {
        "*": {
          "@value": "@id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The result I get:

```
{
  "rootid" : "19718",
  "first_id" : "root_value",
  "second_id" : "second_value",
  "third_id" : "third_value"
}
```

The result I would like to get:

```
{
  "rootid" : "19718",
  "first_id" : "root_value",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick the first object of the array by using `"@ids[0]": "ids"` in order to determine the element indexed with zero, and then add another **shift** transformation similar to the current method such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rootid": "&",
      "@ids[0]": "ids"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rootid": "&",
      "ids": {
        "@value": "@id"
      }
    }
  }
]
```